# ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock:

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (not on ZFS). However, somehow I got this error:

> ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused"

The error screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.

Use apt to remove zsys

> $ sudo apt remove zsys

Then comment out the zsys commands when using apt (put '#' in front of each command) in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90_zsys_system_autosnapshot

> // Takes a snapshot of the system before package changes.
>
> #DPkg::Pre-Invoke {"/usr/libexec/zsys-system-autosnapshot snapshot ||
> true";};
>
> // Update our bootloader to list the new snapshot after the update is
> done to not block the critical path
>
> #DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/usr/libexec/zsys-system-autosnapshot
> update-menu || true";};

I've done this and rebooted and all seems fine adding modules via apt

Comment: Thanks for the first person to reply to me. Can you simplify your ans?

Comment: The file in question is /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90_zsys_system_autosnapshot
I think this has been fixed in the latest updates to Ubuntu (which removes the file if you're not using zsys

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsys/+bug/1881535

Answer (score 1):

Just restart zsysd.service, eveything will be Ok.
The command is `sudo systemctl restart zsysd.service`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I uninstall zsysd from Ubuntu. But anyway, I can reinstall anytime tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because I have a dual-boot system I agree with the option of "comment out" zsys commands per above.  I say this because one could attempt to install the ZFS file system (so I've read) to existing installs of Ubuntu 19.10 (and later?) to make the error go away, but according to the following article attempting to do so will wipe the whole drive, including other functioning partitions!

https://itsfoss.com/zfs-ubuntu/

Currently, I have a second partition on my dual-boot machine running Max OS 11.1 (Big Sur), and wouldn't want that to get wiped.

Finally, I did install of program before and after "comment out" of zsys commands per above and yes, the fix works!  Before: same error as above.  After: no error.  fyi, this is the program I installed (a mail program):

```
sudo apt-get install sylpheed
```